# How can I customise the queryset in SnippetChooserPanel within Wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

Let's say I have a model like this:

```py
class Sandwich(models.Model):
    """
    Food-like things stacked horizontally.
    """

    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    panels = [
        SnippetChooserPanel('owner'),
    ]
```

From within the Wagtail admin I would like the [snippet chooser panel](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/pages/panels.html?#module-wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers) to exclude certain `owners`, e.g. *Steve* cannot be trusted with sandwiches. How do I customise the queryset used?

There is [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/hooks.html#choosers) on how to do this with `PageChooserPanel`, `DocumentChooserPanel` and `ImageChooserPanel`, but not `SnippetChooserPanel`.

**EDIT**

@dan-swains answer worked perfectly, even with a custom `User` model.

```py
@register_snippet
class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    My custom `User` model…
    """

class NoSteveManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Anybody who is not called `Steve`.
        """
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(first_name__iexact='steve')

@register_snippet
class SandwichEater(User):
    """
    Only people who are not a `Steve` are considered sandwich eaters.
    """
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    objects = NoSteveManager()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Django 2.2/Wagtail 2.5, you could try creating a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) and define the [first manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#default-managers) on the model to return the queryset that you need.  I've had [some success](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/4973#issuecomment-494952275) with proxy models in Wagtail although Wagtail needs a bit more work to have proxy models work correctly all the time.

Comment: @Matt just wondering whether you tried this solution and, if so, whether it worked.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly, really clean solution. Thank you!